# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException : module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent.atomic" to unnamed module

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, java-17

I am writing a apache flink program to run locally and interact with google pubsub.

### Dependencies

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.gcp.pubsub.connector.version>3.0.2-1.18</flink.gcp.pubsub.connector.version>
        <flink.version>1.17.0</flink.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-gcp-pubsub</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.gcp.pubsub.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

### Program

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class PubSubExample {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PubSubExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // parse input arguments
        final ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        if (parameterTool.getNumberOfParameters() < 3) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Missing parameters!\n"
                            + "Usage: flink run PubSub.jar --input-subscription <subscription> --input-topicName <topic> --output-topicName <output-topic> "
                            + "--google-project <google project name> ");
            return;
        }

        String projectName = parameterTool.getRequired("google-project");
        String inputTopicName = parameterTool.getRequired("input-topicName");
        String subscriptionName = parameterTool.getRequired("input-subscription");
        String outputTopicName = parameterTool.getRequired("output-topicName");

        PubSubPublisher pubSubPublisher = new PubSubPublisher(projectName, inputTopicName);
        pubSubPublisher.publish(2);

        runFlinkJob(projectName, subscriptionName, outputTopicName);
    }

    private static void runFlinkJob(
            String projectName, String subscriptionName, String outputTopicName) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.enableCheckpointing(1000L);

        env.addSource(
                        PubSubSource.newBuilder()
                                .withDeserializationSchema(new IntegerSerializer())
                                .withProjectName(projectName)
                                .withSubscriptionName(subscriptionName)
                                .withMessageRateLimit(1)
                                .build())
                .map(PubSubExample::printAndReturn)
                .disableChaining()
                .addSink(
                        PubSubSink.newBuilder()
                                .withSerializationSchema(new IntegerSerializer())
                                .withProjectName(projectName)
                                .withTopicName(outputTopicName)
                                .build());

        env.execute("Flink Streaming PubSubReader");
    }

    private static Integer printAndReturn(Integer i) {
        LOG.info("Processed message with payload: " + i);
        return i;
    }
}


import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName;

import java.math.BigInteger;
class PubSubPublisher {
    private final String projectName;
    private final String topicName;

    PubSubPublisher(String projectName, String topicName) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.topicName = topicName;
    }

    /**
     * Publish messages with as payload a single integer. The integers inside the messages start
     * from 0 and increase by one for each message send.
     *
     * @param amountOfMessages amount of messages to send
     */
    void publish(int amountOfMessages) {
        Publisher publisher = null;
        try {
            publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(TopicName.of(projectName, topicName)).build();
            for (int i = 0; i < amountOfMessages; i++) {
                ByteString messageData = ByteString.copyFrom(BigInteger.valueOf(i).toByteArray());
                PubsubMessage message = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(messageData).build();
                publisher.publish(message).get();

                System.out.println("Published message: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(100L);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (publisher != null) {
                    publisher.shutdown();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}


import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SerializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.common.PubSubDeserializationSchema;

import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 * Deserialization schema to deserialize messages produced by {@link PubSubPublisher}. The byte[]
 * received by this schema must contain a single Integer.
 */
class IntegerSerializer
        implements PubSubDeserializationSchema<Integer>, SerializationSchema<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer deserialize(PubsubMessage message) throws IOException {
        return new BigInteger(message.getData().toByteArray()).intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(Integer integer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<Integer> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(Integer integer) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(integer).toByteArray();
    }
}
```

### Error

However when running this program locally gives me following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final long java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent.atomic" to unnamed module @4b5a5ed1
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2317)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.java:1244)
    at example.data.PubSubExample.runFlinkJob(PubSubExample.java:50)
    at example.data.PubSubExample.main(PubSubExample.java:33)
```

### Attempt 1

I have added below options in VM options but still error happens.

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

### Attempt 2

I tried to degrade java version to 11 as well but that didn't help.

Can someone please help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `--add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED` ?

Comment: This ususally happens if there is conflict in the Java versions, for example if you have different version installed on the laptop and IntelliJ uses a different version. Could be unlikely in your case but worth checking it.

Comment: You're adding Scala 2.10, but that is not supported by Flink. I'm also not sure that the GCP Pubsub connector is compatible with JDK17. At least it's not tested against that JDK version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attempting to replicate the issue locally, you might consider resolving it by adding the following parameters in the **JVM**：

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).